# Place two positive x-axes of different range beside each other (Excel 2021)

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2021

I was wondering if there is a way to reproduce this kind of graph in Excel 2021. The reason being is a need to compare two sets of data. They have a similar y-axis, which is time in seconds, but the left set has x-values from 0-16 and the right set has x-values from 150 to -100  [image: SampleGraph, Y-axis is Time, X-axis is Distance]

Many thanks!

What I've seen so far is adding a secondary x-axis but this does not quite place things side-by-side like I want to, at the same time I am dealing with ,technically, two different x-axes of different ranges.

Comment: Make 1 data set combining all the values.

Comment: @SolarMike but if I do that it will just be one x-axis with 150 to -100 range. I need the graph to look exactly like the one above. Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding, could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: So you show a graph with 1 x-axis - why is that not what you want?

Comment: @SolarMike It's not. Because it has to be two ranges as I said in my post, one for 16<--0 and one for 150 <--0---> -100 (please refer to the picture)

Comment: Why can't you fit the values of 0 - 16 in amongst the values 150 to -100 ? This would make 1 data set.

Comment: I understand, I can do that, but I need to separate the 16<--0 x-range, the reason being is I need to emphasize this particular trendline, from the rest of the trendlines in the 150 <--0---> -100 x-range, but they all have have to be in one graph as seen in the picture.